# Scaled option for tick numbers' size

Tags: plotting, fonts, ticks, size

For axes label the scaled `FontSize` works like charm. If I do:

```
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["x", FontSize -> Scaled[0.04]], 
   Style["sin(x)", FontSize -> Scaled[0.04]]}]
```

When I grab the handle of the plot and rescale it, the $x$ and $\sin(x)$ labels are scaled with it. More importantly, if I export the plot in a large resolution, like

```
Export["Test.png", 
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, 
  AxesLabel -> {Style["x", FontSize -> Scaled[0.04]], 
    Style["sin(x)", FontSize -> Scaled[0.04]]}], ImageSize -> 3840]
```

the text is reasonably big to see it. However, the tick labelings (numbers) are not, so I adjust them too:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["x", FontSize -> Scaled[0.04]], 
   Style["sin(x)", FontSize -> Scaled[0.04]]}, 
 TicksStyle -> Scaled[0.02]]
```

Ticks just got bigger than default, that's for sure. But if I grab the handle and rescale the plot, they don't rescale with it. No matter what I do, option `Scaled` just doesn't work here. What should I do? I export various image sizes, I can't adjust the font size individually for every plot.

Comment: try `BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> Scaled[0.02]}` in place of ` TicksStyle -> Scaled[0.02]`?

Comment: Thank you, but that changed also the size of "x" and "sin(x)". How do i prevent that? Will it also work for the frame tims in the case of density plot?